# Can't access data from a specific file

Tags: jekyll

I've created a file called `people.yml` inside of the `_data` folder. I have a page `people.html` where I'm trying to access the information from the data file. It seems like I can only get the info when I create a `for loop`. I'm referencing the examples found [here](https://idratherbewriting.com/documentation-theme-jekyll/mydoc_yaml_tutorial.html) to accomplish this. Can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

**people.yml**

```
- id: 123
  name: John Does
  type: A
```

**people.html**

```
<h1>Person</h1>
<p class="name">{{ site.data.people.name }}</p>
<span class="type">{{ site.data.people.type }}</span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've made the data in your people.yml file an array by adding the `-`. If you want to access it *not* in a loop, you'll need to remove the hypen.

```yaml
id: 123
name: John Does
type: A
```

Then calling `{{ site.data.people.name }}` should return "John Does".

Comment: Great! It's now working. Thank you for your help!